# Flutter Tab bar - How to assign diffrent color of each selected Tab?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, tabbar, flutter-widget

```
TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
            indicator: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                16.0,
              ),
              color: colors[_tabController.index],
            ),
            tabs: const [
              Tab(text: "INFO"),
              Tab(text: "ENGAGEMENT"),
              Tab(text: "TRACK"),
            ],
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 13,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 13,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I wanted Each Tab to have a Different color when they're selected
So I tried to change the color when the index changes by storing them in a list
But it doesnt work without setState (I know its not changing the state because the color changes after quick reload)[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can include a listener on `TabController` and call `setState` there.

```dart
  _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below should do the trick. The missing part of your approach is a `setState` to refresh the screen with the current selected tab index. Check out the screen recording and the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d45cffbf73ae3e6713cf36cc2c82248d):

The [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) do almost all the job already. Only the outside round border should be customized and it's just a matter of wrapping the `TabBar` into a [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html). `Containers` are pretty easy to work with and highly customizable.

[image]

And here's the code itself as a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

const colors = [
  Color(0xFF64c636),
  Color(0xFFf2c32c),
  Color(0xFF00a9ce),
];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  int _tabIndex = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() => _tabIndex = tabController.index);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 48,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          border: Border.all(width: 2),
        ),
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorWeight: 0,
          controller: tabController,
          indicator: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                16.0,
              ),
              color: colors[_tabIndex],
            ),
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
          splashBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          tabs: const [
            Tab(text: 'INFO'),
            Tab(text: 'ENGAGEMENT'),
            Tab(text: 'TRACK'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this before too I was just using the color property on TabBar() widget
Do you know why it doesnt work when I use it there because doing it this way loses the smooth animation thats inbuilt in flutter tab bar
(check color : colors[_tabController.index] in my code)

Comment: I've updated my answer to keep the animation. Please check [the code and live demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d45cffbf73ae3e6713cf36cc2c82248d) again (I'll update the screen recording ASAP). I've just updated it with your approach.